# yahoo sitebuilder facebook like box not working

Tags: yahoo, facebook-likebox

I have used facebook like box in the past with yahoo sitebuilder and never had any problem creating code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ and pasting it to html box. Now with facebook changes it wont work any more.

past code: (works fine)

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%23%21%2Fpages%2FCedar-Park-TX%2FPromotional-Product-Specialty%2F113782388677670&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=587" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:587px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

new code: (doesnt work)

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPromotional-Product-Specialty%2F113782388677670&amp;width=292&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;appId=306388216066339" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this bug as well, what you have to do is put http: infront of the //www.facebook.com
so it goes from this:

`<iframe src=//www.facebook.com..........`

to this:

`<iframe src=http://www.facebook.com..........`